# Software and Hardware needed to run a USB camera?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Watchport™/V USB. camera without any cable or any software. How can I use this hardware
I am running a Windows 7 based pc with 500 gb HD and 4 gb Ram...

Comment: Is there no manual with your hardware?

Comment: If you don't have the cable then the cmera cannot be used.  If you had the cable the drivers could be found on the Watchport website.

Answer (score 1):

For help installing and cable, refer to [this](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000406_E.pdf).

For Drivers, they are [here](http://www.helpdrivers.com/others/Digi/WatchPort-V_USB/)

Note: used drivers from this website before for an oldie Windows NT and worked like a charm, so from my own experience it is trustable.